# Lorenz Curve Intersections

Tags: graphing-functions

Can two Lorenz Curves representing different study areas when plotted together on the same axes, ever intersect except at their start and end points?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course two Lorenz curves can intersect when plotted on the same axes not counting their start and end points.

See this: [Crossing Lorenz Curves](https://theses.univ-lyon2.fr/documents/getpart.php?id=lyon2.2006.sommeiller_e&part=122239). And this: [Can two Lorenz curves intersect?](https://www.quora.com/Can-two-lorenz-curve-intersect)

However when Lorenz curves intersect there will be ambiguity when trying to determine which curve represents more inequality (as noted in the links).